# Match multiple columns with same value in ODBC

Tags: odbc, match

Hi I have an Access Table like this.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   firstname        |    surname         |   address          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Joan             |    Rivers          | 123 Fake St.       |
|   Michael          |    Jackson         | 69 Balls Head St.  |
|   Justin           |    Bieber          | None               |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm wondering if it is possible, over ODBC, to construct a query that allows me to match my input to any column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM NEMESISES WHERE '%value%' LIKE firstname or surname or address;
```

and when value is plugged in for example: '%bie%', it outputs the Justin Bieber row or when '%st%' is plugged in it outputs the Joan Rivers and Michael Jackson row.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide it into 3 matchings:

```
SELECT * FROM NEMESISES
WHERE firstname LIKE '%value%'
    OR surname LIKE '%value%'
    OR address LIKE '%value%';
```

Or you can match joined values of columns:

```
SELECT * FROM NEMESISES
WHERE firstname || surname || address LIKE '%value%';
```

I would prefer first solution: database have less to do.